# Built Docker image cannot reach postgreSQL

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-build

I am using Django and PostgreSQL as different containers for a project. When I run the containers using `docker-compose up`, my Django application can connect to the PostgreSQL, but the same, when I build the docker image with `docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag rengine:$(date +%s)`, the image successfully builds, but on the entrypoint.sh, it is unable to find host as db.

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        restart: always
        image: "postgres:12.3-alpine"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        networks:
            - rengine_network
    web:
        restart: always
        build: .
        command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - .:/app
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - rengine_network

networks:
    rengine_network:
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z db 5432; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py migrate

# Load default engine types
python manage.py loaddata fixtures/default_scan_engines.json --app scanEngine.EngineType

exec "$@"
```

and Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM python:3-alpine

# Labels and Credits
LABEL \
    name="reNgine" \
    author="Yogesh Ojha <yogesh.ojha11@gmail.com>" \
    description="reNgine is a automated pipeline of recon process, useful for information gathering during web application penetration testing."

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && apk add chromium \
    && apk add git \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

# Copy requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

# Download and install go 1.13
COPY --from=golang:1.13-alpine /usr/local/go/ /usr/local/go/

# Environment vars
ENV DATABASE="postgres"
ENV GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
ENV GOPATH="/root/go"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${GOROOT}/bin"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin"

# Download Go packages
RUN go get -u github.com/tomnomnom/assetfinder github.com/hakluke/hakrawler github.com/haccer/subjack

RUN GO111MODULE=on go get -u -v github.com/projectdiscovery/httpx/cmd/httpx \
    github.com/projectdiscovery/naabu/cmd/naabu \
    github.com/projectdiscovery/subfinder/cmd/subfinder \
    github.com/lc/gau

# Make directory for app
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy source code
COPY . /app/

# Collect Static
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear

RUN chmod +x /app/tools/get_subdomain.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/tools/get_dirs.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/tools/get_urls.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/tools/takeover.sh

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I run the build image, it says no such host db, on entrypoint.sh file.

Can somebody help me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: "image successfully builds, but on the entrypoint.sh, it is unable to find host as db" ? how you got this error at build time?

Comment: No, the build is successful. When I run the image with docker run rengine:1234, I get this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on a comment the error appeared during

```
docker run rengine:1234,
```

So the error is expected in this case, as hostname `db` will only work in the docker-compose network. Inside docker-compose stack one service can communicate with other service using `service name`, but in case of `docker run` both container running in isolated environment.

You have two option to resolve this issue

- Run the DB container and use [legacy-link](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#:%7E:text=Network%20port%20mappings%20are%20not,information%20from%20one%20to%20another.) to link the application container with `DB`

```
docker run -it --name db mydb_image
# now link application container
docker run -it --link db:db rengine:1234
```

Now the container will able to communicate with host `db`.

- Second option is to create `docker network` and then run both container in same network.

```
docker run -itd --network=mynetwork db

docker run -itd --network=mynetwork app
```

But you are already using docker-compose, so better to do testing with docker-compose.